# Remove '\n.\n' C++

Tags: c++, string

If i have a string as such

```
"I am not here... \n..Hello\n.\n....Whats happening"
```

I want to replace the above string so:

```
"I am not here... \n..Hello\n. \n....Whats happening"
                              ^ Space added
```

Just a bit of a background on what im doing. Im using sendmail in C++ and `\n.\n` is `End Of Message` Equivalent of *sendmail*. I just created a class that uses sendmail to send mails. but obviously if the user from the outsite gives sendmail that command i want it to be removed. Here is my message function just incase.:

```
//Operator to add to the message
void operator<<(string imessage){
    if (imessage != ""){ message += imessage; } 
}
```

How would i go about doing this. Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Don't forget to check for `.\n` at the *start* of the message too.

Comment: It might be a better idea to add newlines at the beginning and end of the message before sending it. This is all part of an encoding process anyway.

Comment: Ooo thanks. :D '.\n' forgot about that. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my last version :)
This code handles the case mentioned by @Greg Hewgill

```
string& format_text(string& str)
{
    const string::size_type dot_offset = 2;
    string::size_type found_at_start = str.find("\n.\n"),
                    found_at = str.find("\n.\n");

    if(found_at_start != string::npos)
        str.insert(0, " ");

    while(found_at != string::npos)
    {
        str.insert(found_at+dot_offset+1, " ");
        found_at = str.find("\n.\n", found_at+1);
    }
    return str;
}

int main()
{
    string text = ".\nn\n.\nn";
    std::cout << format_text(text);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Look up String.find and String.replace

For example (not tested)

```
string endOfMessage = "\n.\n";
string replacement = "\n. \n";
size_t position;

while (position = message.find(endOfMessage))
{
   message.replace(position, endOfMessage.length(), replacement);
}
```

Comment: This will A. perform horribly and B. break if the source and replacement are the same, or any part of the replacement is the source. See my answer for a corrected version....

Comment: Oh, and find returns npos rather than 0 on failure.

Answer (score 2):

This is derived from Dan McG's answer so upvote him ;)

```
string endOfMessage = "\n.\n";
string replacement = "\n. \n";
size_t position;

while (position = message.find(endOfMessage, position) != message.npos)
{
   message.replace(position, endOfMessage.length(), replacement);
   position += replacement.length();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Boost has [Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) (a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) module). Might be overkill if this is the only replacement you need to do.

Comment: Yes a bit overkill, but i was wondering for later what regex functionality does C++ have. Plus 1 for solving that :D

Comment: i need that for nl2br function for C :D

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::search` and the `insert` method of sequence containers such as `string`, `deque`, or whatever you use to store the message text.

```
typedef std::string::iterator SIter; // or whatever container you use
static const char *end_seq = "\n.\n";
for ( SIter tricky_begin = msg.begin();
  tricky_begin = std::search( tricky_begin, msg.end(), end_seq, end_seq+3 ),
  tricky_begin != msg.end(); ) {
    tricky_begin = msg.insert( tricky_begin + 2, ' ' );
}
```

Comment: As for the newline-at-beginning issue, you should initialize the message with a leading newline and keep it there. Sounds like a broad semantic issue of the SMTP format.